# Optical flow and focus of expansion in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, vision, opticalflow

I am currently working on a project that requires me to find the focus of expansion using optical flow.

I currently have the optical flow and am using the formula from pages 13-14 this paper:
http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~donovan/stabilization/opticalflow.pdf

I take two frames from a video and find pyramids from both using buildOpticalFlowPyramid then find the keypoints using goodFeaturesToTrack. Using these I then calculate the sparse optical flow with calcOpticalFlowPyrLK. All three of these methods are provided by OpenCV.

The problem I have hit is that I need both the flow vector for each keypoint in the image to fill the A and b matrices. Would the pixel value be just the location of the keypoint in the original image? And then the flow vector is the difference between the initial location and new point?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is precisely so. Using the terms/variables as per the paper and the following link,

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk

**p_i** = *(x,y)* are the *prevPts* (points in the original image),

**v** = *(u,v)* are the flow vectors obtained by subtracting points in *prevPts* from those in *nextPts*.